# font awesome icons do only work at safari

Tags: icons, font-awesome

unfortunately the font awesome icons do only work with safari and not with any other browser. I want to implement the html code and css to my online shop. 
Do you know how to fix it ?

Link to the html template below..

```
<https://codepen.io/rifabii/pen/PoqrwrE>
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Please be much more specific. Include the relevant code snippet(s) in your question and explain exactly what problem you are seeing. This will make it possible to answer your question and help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `font-weight: normal;` in this :

```
.service-box .service-icon .front-content i {
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: normal;
}
```